How to resolve getWritableDatabase() SELinux audit error: denied { ioctl }? (Android 14)
I encountered an issue where getWritableDatabase() from SQLiteOpenHelper in my Android app throws an SELinux audit error. It still works but in logcat I can see that error. The specific log entry looks like this:
type=1400 audit(): avc: denied { ioctl } for pid=23711 comm="RxComputationTh" path="/data/data/com.my.app/databases/db" ioctlcmd=0xf522 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0 SEPF_SM-S901B_12_0001 audit_filtered
I tried to find if any new permission should be added for Android 14, but there isn't anything. This doesn't happen on Android 12 and below. I guess the app should be trusted somehow by the system and not by Google Play while publishing. Does anyone have an idea why is this happening?
